# create EC2 instance in JAVA AWS sdk using snapshot

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I can create an EC2 instance using java sdk using some image. Currently I am creating it like this

```
 private static void createInstance()
            throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException, InterruptedException
    {
        RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
        .withInstanceType("m1.small")
        .withImageId("ami-e565ba8c")
        .withMinCount(1)
        .withMaxCount(1)
        .withKeyName("mykey")
        ;
        RunInstancesResult runInstances = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);


    }
```

Can someone please guide me that how can I create ec2 instance using snapshot of image instead of image itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to create image from the snapshot first. Then you can launch instance from that image.

Comment: but how? -1 for not explaining anything but the obvious.